# How to declare 8-bit unsigned integer in ruby?

Tags: ruby, integer, unsigned

In c++ you can do:

`uint8 foo_bar`

How would we do the same thing in ruby? Any alternatives?

[This post seems close to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301259/using-ruby-to-convert-unsigned-integers-stored-as-signed-back-to-the-original-val) maybe someone can explain?

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem: you want to do X and you think Y (uint8) will help. What's your X?

Comment: I was switching over a program written in VB or something into ruby.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ruby abstracts away the internal storage of integers, so you don't have to worry about it.

If you assign an integer to a variable, Ruby will deal with the internals, allocating memory when needed. Smaller integers are of type [`Fixnum`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Fixnum.html) (stored in a single word), larger integers are of type [`Bignum`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Bignum.html).

```
a = 64
a.class  #=> Fixnum; stored in a single word
a += 1234567890
a.class  #=> Bignum; stored in more than a single word
```

Ruby is dynamically typed, so you cannot force a variable to contain only unsigned 8-bit integers (just as you cannot force a variable to only contain string values, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

You don't declare types in Ruby. The language is dynamically typed.