# How to do unsigned byte operation in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to do some bit operation on ruby.
One of the data I need it to be unsigned int to get the correct value.
However when I add ,this number is always int,

How to declare a variable as unsigned int? I've been searched but seems none answer my question.

The other post says I can't declare a unsigned variable in Ruby.

#### Changed Question:

How to do unsigned subtraction in Ruby on Rails?
I need do some byte checksum, which requires unsigned operation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to declare 8-bit unsigned integer in ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335710/how-to-declare-8-bit-unsigned-integer-in-ruby)

Comment: On the topic of bitwise operations, you might [find this useful](http://calleerlandsson.com/2014/02/06/rubys-bitwise-operators/)

Comment: @sjagr thank you,I have read both posts,the first one cant answer my question...I need force or declare a datatype to be unsigned...the second one I have tried,use the number directly and,but result is wrong.maybe I need to convert to_s(2) then do the and operation?

Comment: The first post answers your question by saying you can't do such a thing thanks to Ruby's abstraction. The second post is very comprehensive and talks about the gotchas - you should read it again.

Answer (score 0):

Types are dynamic in Ruby. Ruby implements integers in such a way that the distinction `signed`/`unsigned` is irrelevant, as Ruby integers extend automatically into BigNum (arbitrary length integers) when applicable.